# PSQL join - Column "table.column" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, inner-join

I need to update records in a table but only if a certain column of this table equals the content of a column of another table. 
But first, just to be sure, I want to select all of the records that meets this specific so I've tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM "table1" as ARR INNER JOIN "table2" as AOP ON ("AOP.col2" = "ARR.col1");
```

But the query returns this error:

> ERROR:  column "AOP.col2" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...as ARR INNER JOIN "table2" as AOP ON ("AOP.col...

What am I doing wrong? (obviously the column does exist) 
Seeing this error do you think the following update query will also fail?

```
UPDATE "table2" AS AOP
SET "col2" = "ARR.col1"
FROM "table1" AS ARR
WHERE "AOP.col3" = "ARR.col4";
```

Comment: Remove all those useless double quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SOLVED]
If anyone's interested in the solution this is it:

```
SELECT * FROM "table1" as "ARR" INNER JOIN "table2" as "AOP" ON ("AOP"."col2" = "ARR"."col1");
```

Comment: I would highly recommend to remove all those useless double quotes and never use quoted identifiers. That will give you a lot less headaches in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table1 ARR INNER JOIN table2 AOP ON AOP.col2=ARR.col1